Scattering theory in Weinberg's QFT
I learned scattering theory a couple of times but never really understand. I summarize my preliminary understanding of scattering theory in Weinberg's QFT, then raise my questions.
(1)The natural and probably only logical definition of free particle states are those that transform as tensor products of (an arbitrary number of) single particle states. We label them by $\Phi_\alpha$ with $\alpha$ including each particle's species, momentum, and spin (helicity). The Poincare group generators of the free particle states are denoted by $P^{(0)}_\mu,J^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}$.
(2)These free particle states span the whole Hilbert space. As a result, once free particle states are specified, the free Poincare group generators are uniquely determined by their action on these states. By the transformation law, free particle states are eigenstates of the free Hamiltonian $H^{(0)} = {P^{(0)}}^0$ with eigenvalues being the sum of the energy of each particles. We denote the total energy by $E_\alpha$.
(3)The free Hamiltonian plays a special role in free Poincare group generators. It connects "free" and "interacting". An in-state $\Psi^+_\alpha$ is a state that looks like a free particle state $\Phi_\alpha$ in the infinite past, namely $e^{-iHt}\Psi^+_\alpha \sim e^{-iH^{(0)}t}\Phi_\alpha$ as $t\to -\infty$ or more precisely
\begin{align}
 \Psi^+_\alpha = \lim_{t\to -\infty} e^{iHt} e^{-iH^{(0)}t}\Phi_\alpha := \Omega_+ \Phi_\alpha
\end{align}
Similarly for out-states.
(4)The existence of the Moller wave operator $\Omega_{\pm}$ (existence of the limit) restricts our choice of the free Hamiltonian $H^{(0)}$ and in general the choice of the "free sector".
(5)It follows from the definition that $\Psi^{\pm}_\alpha$ are eigenstates of $H$ with eigenvalue $E_\alpha$. Moreover we have the intertwine relation by acting on the complete set $\Phi_\alpha$
\begin{align}
 \Omega_{\pm} H^{(0)} = H \Omega_{\pm}
\end{align}
In addition, since there are bound states in the interacting theory, $\Psi^{\pm}_\alpha$ do not span the Hilbert space. In other words, $\Omega_\pm$ are isometric but not invertible (not surjective). They are isomorphisms from the Hilbert space to its proper subspace.
My questions are:
(a) How do we choose the "free sector" in practice? To what extent is the choice unique?
(b) I fancy intertwine relations extended to other Poincare group generators, how can that be derived? Is it sensible that we take this as part of the definition, that in/out-states have the same quantum number as the corresponding free particle states? How would this affect question (a)?
(c) Weinberg insists that $H^{(0)}$ has the same spectrum as $H$, so bound states are introduced into $H^{(0)}$ as elementary particles. What does this mean?
By the way, a thorough explanation may need some operator theory which I know nothing of. It would nice if it's explained in a way easy to understand without full math rigor.

$\Psi_\alpha^\pm$ does span the Hilbert space. All bound states of $H$ are included in the free Hamiltonian $H_0$ as free particle states. The idea in scattering theory is that we should treat the interaction $V$ as "small". It's most definitely, not allowed to change the Hilbert space its acting on. That's why any bound states in $H$ must be included in $H_0$. This is clearly mentioned in Weinberg below equation (3.1.10)

UPDATE: I didn't read the question fully before commenting. I apologize for that. What Weinberg means is that if there exists, for example, a spin-0 bound state particle with (physical) mass $m$ in the spectrum of $H$, then we should add the term $-\frac{1}{2} ( \partial \phi )^2 + \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2$ to $H_0$. Thus, in $H_0$, this particle is treated as an elementary particle.

As an example, in QCD, one starts with the quarks as fundamental particle, so we introduce fields $q$ for each quark. The spectrum of $H$ contains pions. We must therefore introduce a new field $\pi$ corresponding to this bound state in $H_0$. So, the fields in $H_0$ are $q$ and $\pi$. Of course, in the full theory (described by $H$), $\pi$ is not independent of $q$ ($\pi \sim {\bar q} q$), but in the free theory, they are independent fields.

@Prahar Thanks for your detailed explanation. I am totally unaware of this, and in fact get quite confused. If a new field $\pi$ independent of $q$ is introduced, aren't we enlarging the Hilbert space? Does that mean in the free theory, the bound state pion has to be generated by $\pi$ only and cannot be generated by $q$? Also, could you kindly point me to some references about this, textbooks or notes?

@Prahar It probably makes sense to include bound states in $H_0$ to make $V$ small. However in Quantum Mechanics scattering, we usually choose $H_0=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2$, which only has scattering states as eigenstates.

@Prahar My previous understanding (may well be wrong) is, even if $H_0$ doesn't include bound states, eigenstates of $H_0$ still span the same Hilbert space. Much like in QM scattering planewaves span the Hilbert space including bound states. There is no need to introduce an independent new field to generate a bound state, it's generated by free fields (creation/annihilation operators), just not a simple expression.
